# Gaps in simple plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to recreate [*this*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340223/plot-of-a-square) which should be fairly straightforward with `ParametricPlot`, but wondering why this doesn't work:

```
With[{p = 20}, Plot[{(1 - x^(2 p))^(1/(2 p)), -(1 - x^(2 p))^(1/(2 p))}, 
{x, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, GridLines -> 
Automatic, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[.005], Darker@Red}}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have tried playing around with `MaxRecursion`, `WorkingPrecision`, `PlotPoints` etc. to no avail.

Comment: You could use `ContourPlot[]` on the associated implicit equation instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get a function value of 10^-1 you need to evaluate the function at x = 1 - 10^-40 . That's a pretty fine grained step

Here is a cheap alternative:

```
f[x_, _] := {0, 0} /; (! -1 < x < 1.)
f[x_, p_] := (1 - x^p)^(1/p) {1, -1}

Plot[f[x, 40], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(Plot[f[x, #], {x, -1.5, 1.5}, AspectRatio -> Automatic] & /@  Range[2, 40, 2]) // Show
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: nice - thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

If you express your equation in polar coordinates, vertical lines won't be an issue:

```
x^(2 p) + y^(2 p) == 1 /. {x -> r Cos[θ], y -> r Sin[θ]} // PowerExpand
```

> ```
> r^(2 p) Cos[θ]^(2 p) + r^(2 p) Sin[θ]^(2 p) == 1
> ```

```
With[{p = 20},
  PolarPlot[(1/(Cos[θ]^(2 p) + Sin[θ]^(2 p)))^(1/(2 p)), {θ, 0, 2π}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: great - yes, `PolarPlot` seems the most straightfoirward option - I was just wondering why my approach in the OP didn't work :)

Comment: Ah, I should learn to read!

Comment: Ha! Good tip with `PowerExand` though - nice ref :)

Answer (score 5):

You could also add a [`UnitBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitBox.html) and expand the plot range just a little to catch the zeros:

```
With[{p = 20}, 
 Plot[
   UnitBox[x/2]*{(1 - x^(2 p))^(1/(2 p)), -(1 - x^(2 p))^(1/(2 p))},
   {x, -1.0001, 1.0001},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[.005], Darker@Red}},
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}
 ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: neat trick! I'll remember that one :)